# Why will my text not change color on modal box?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a line of code where the user will click on the text, which will change color to red. This is linked to a checkbox feature which is checked every time the text is red. The checkbox is meant to be invisible by the way. But for the purpose of helping me I have increased the opacity to 100 instead of 0.

I am oblivious as to why the code wont work when I place it inside code for a modal box, which is where I want it to be in the first place.

The text changes color only when you interact with the checkbox, but I also want it to change the color when it gets clicked.

```js
  $('a[href="#ex5"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).modal({
      escapeClose: false,
      clickClose: false,
      showClose: false,
    });
  });
```

```css
.onlyThese{
 cursor:pointer;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    opacity: 100;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="sector-print-temp">
  <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
</div>

<p> <a class="btn" href="#ex5">Sectors </a> </p>
     
<div id="ex5"  class="modal"  style="background-color:white">
  <div style="float:left;">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="group1" class="sector-print-temp">
      <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
      <p style="float:right"> 
      <a href="#" rel="modal:close"  class="onlyThese;"> <b>Apply</b> </a> 
      </p>    
  </div>
</div>
```

My expectations of the code should be the following:

- The user clicks on the text
- Text changes color to red
- When the text changes color to red, the checkbox is checked

Comment: FWIW - `opacity` has a maximum of ONE!

Comment: I'd suggest it's because you have two checkboxes / labels using the SAME ID. Change one of them.

Comment: Don't run 3 jQuery versions at a time... One is enought.

Comment: How do I know which is the correct one to use though, also is me running more than one harmful to my code?

Comment: smply read the documentation : https://jquery.com/download/  jQuery last version is actualy  3.4.1  --it's like any product, you have to pay attention to the expiry dates

Comment: ... and yes, has **Paulie_D 45** wrote you have 2 elements with the same id => **id must be unique**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's useless to try to do such complicated things, the CSS allows to directly fix this question, whether in a modal window or not

```css
input[type="checkbox"] { display: none }
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label { color:red }

.onlyThese { cursor: pointer }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="group1"> <label for="group1" class="onlyThese">Publication </label>
```